# Keep jquery animate when refreshing AJAX content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Basically i search for a way to refresh AJAX content but keep jquery animate effect
across refreshes.

In simpler terms:
I refresh div every second.
On first refresh i set animate the color of div.
Next second breaks animate effect and turns div color into default.

Do you have any ideas how to keep it across refreshes?

I refresh with:

```
$("#mydiv").html(ajaxContent)
```

**EDIT:**
I made a fiddle but it works on that site. So it seems that @Flash Thunder
is right, the problem has to be somewhere else.

**EDIT 2 :**
Problem is that i load innerDivs inside myDiv.
My Call removes the div from DOM so it looses style also.
Hers example of problem: http://jsfiddle.net/X5PVu/1/

Comment: `I refresh div every second.` This is a bad idea in itself. If you need that level of persistence use WebSockets.

Comment: This has to be the problem of your animation function not the content change.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - i'm doing prototype, i will probably move to WebSockets in full web page.

Comment: You're going to have to share more than one line of code if you want some help with your problem. How about making a jsFiddle?

Comment: @FlashThunder Doesn't .html remove css effects?

Comment: please post what you have tried.

Comment: I'll post a jsFiddle in a moment.

Comment: @Jask: No, when it is DIV (#mydiv), that has a style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animations take the initial step and process until final step, whatever the initial step is.

If you go from 0 to 10 and replaces an element while it's at 3, just retrieve that 3 value and set it to the new element, then start the animation again : it will start at 3 and continue up to 10.

So you could basically, before replacing content, find the current color, and set it directly to the new element, then start again the animation :

```
var $old_el = $( '#your_el' );
$new_el.css( 'backgroundColor', $old_el.css( 'backgroundColor' ));
$old_el.replaceWith( $new_el );
$new_el.animate( 'backgroundColor', your_destination_color );
```

See for an example : http://jsfiddle.net/44RL8/

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do this fiddle based on your example http://jsfiddle.net/X5PVu/5/